# TSQL Oddity with String_Agg

Tags: sql-server

This query returns the wrong results for the second string Agg function:

```
select
string_agg(t.name, ';') as BBB,
string_agg(t.name, ', ' ) as CCC
from sys.tables as t
```

But it works if you alter t.name eg:

```
select
string_agg(t.name, ';') as BBB,
string_agg('' + t.name, ', ' ) as CCC
from sys.tables as t
```

Any idea why?  Is this a bug?

Comment: It is most probably a bug. If you add the optional `WITHIN GROUP` clause the result is ok: `string_agg(t.name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.name ASC) as CCC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting, it is a bug, sure.
It checks the first argument and use it as a cache for the second.

It runs odd on sys.* objects

But the query runs successfully on other database tables.

I executed the exact query with execution plan.

[image]

And what is more interesting, when I executed the query on a user database on a different table, the query returns expected data.

There is no error in this case

[image]